# In DataTables jedit, Cant get the row id?

Tags: jquery

I am using Datatables jedit,I cant get the rowid.i.e i want to assign unique id and get it?

Comment: Are you unsure if you want to get it?

Answer (score 0):

From [this example](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html) on the datatables website, the ID is automatically added to the row.  When your script does a submit to the ajax source, the ID will be passed to the script as a `$_REQUEST` variable.

If you need more than that, you'll have to explain your question better.